# How to change saved folder when download Jupyter notebook downloaded as HTML?

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to download jupyter notebook as HTML using menu of File->Download As-> HTML(*.html), however the downloaded html is saved in  c:\temp. How to save it under working folder?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to move it where you want it after downloading?  It would certainly be quicker than waiting for an answer in a group like this.

Comment: I know, I have many to convert and I have to do it many times as well. it would be nice to solve this issue

Comment: The problem is, Jupyter runs in a browser, which means it has very limited access to your computer.  It can't go exploring your filesystem -- that's a security hole.  It can download to your default download location.